# * What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':expo-updates:kaptDebugKotlin'

Tags: android, react-native, expo, expo-updates

Am using expo-updates for the release channel in Bare React Native, it's working fine with expo Go but while I try to run `react-native run-android` my app gets launched but crashes.

> - What went wrong:
>   Execution failed for task ':expo-updates:kaptDebugKotlin'.
>   A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
>   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)

i tried to fix this issue with room version   `def room_version = "2.3.0"` and   `def room_version = "2.4.2"` and tried with lower versions of expo Updates. Am using MacBook M1 chip. this issue comes only in android. Give any suggestions to fix this issue.

> ```
> "expo-status-bar": "~1.2.0",
> ```

```
"expo-updates": "~0.11.7",
"firebase": "8.2.3",
"metro": "^0.66.2",
"native-base": "^2.13.5",
"react": "17.0.1",
"react-dom": "17.0.1",
"react-native": "0.64.3",
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? Even I'm stuck with this same error when trying to build for android.